# Hardware acceleration flag

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-2.2-froyo

I'm building an app which will run from Android version 2.2 (Froyo) onwards. I have already built an app with 2.2 for playing videos and in the same app I want to run on Android version 3 (Honeycomb).

And here my problem starts with hardware_ accelerated flag. This flag is available from Honeycomb 3 onwards, but not below Honeycomb. I want to ship one common app with Froyo, but as I'm trying my app in Honeycomb, video is not shown. It's clearly because of the hardware_ accelerated flag. I can release two builds, but I just want to give one try. Can I avoid that?

My problem is I want to ship the app with Froyo, but for hardware_accelerated flag, it has a reference, not a manifest or in the programmatically coding since it's Froyo. I'm using webview from where the videos will be played.

Comment: For my app the hardware acceleration does not matter it also plays on older devices.

Comment: @rekire i m streaming the videos from web services so i need hardware_accelerated enabled. and one more thing i just develop app for the 2.2(froyo). In which version you have developed and how many versions it supports.

Comment: My app also streams the videos, I support API 8-17. And tested on API 7, 10, 14, 17. I could not support API 7 due I could not set cookies. The other parts of my app also supports API 5.

Comment: i m using webview, i have just edited my question.

Comment: I'm using `VideoView` or `TextureView` depending on the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the trick the other way around. I built an app in Honeycomb (Android 3.0) itself. And allowed to support Froyo (Android 2.2) in the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Tried to set only the window in hardware accelerated mode:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
}
```

And your manifest shoud set [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) compatibility to:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

And add the android-support-v4.jar lib to your project.

However, your problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: i cannot use your piece of code, since these flags are not available on froyo.

Comment: thanks for ur presious time but `Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB` line of code i cant add since i want to run build on froyo, however i solved my problem myself. please check my ans