# BUG: createWindowSurface failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I have an application on Google Play for counting down numbers and letters. In this application I have the following activities:

- google sigin
- archivements
- admob service

I use Google Analytics, and ACRA for error reporting. I don't use GLsurfaceView, but I use ACRA one or two times a day which gives me these errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: createWindowSurface failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:763)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createEglSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:663)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:502)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1325)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2467)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anyone know what happened? I don't use surfaceView; can anyone help me?

Comment: Got it fixed ? I think its because of admob

Comment: Are you using images as activity's background? Devices have a maximum resolution of the images that can manage (it differs depending of the devices), if you are trying to create and use an image larger than that resolution, you'll get a GL Error.

Comment: Maybe its for admob, what can i do? i have images on background, but it weight is 80kb...

Comment: Same problem, few observations about this exception: 1. Android 4.0 & 4.1, 2. Tablets, 3. GPU: Mali 400, 4. Not found on Samsung devices.

Comment: I saw this today working on a custom animated transition.  I'm seeing it on a Note3 on stock 4.4.2.  Not seeing it on a Moto G on 4.4.2 or Nexus 5 on 5.0 (LPX13D).  It's consistent on the Note3.  Pretty complex animation moving four variables using ObjectAnimator on a few different objects.  I have two workarounds so far... 1) reduce complexity of animation.  2.) add a black background behind the animating views (technically there is no background behind the transitioning views in the interest of of reducing overdraw).  These workarounds aren't terribly scientific/could be coincidence.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and found that the problem is related to WebView(s) and hardware acceleration on some devices.

Instead of turning off completely hardware acceleration, I disabled it for all my WebView(s) **including the AdMob view**!

Here how to do it:

```
adView = new AdView(this); //or get it with findViewById()
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
   adView.setLayerType(AdView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); //instead of LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with InterstitialAd?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried disabling hardware acceleration for your app (it's utilizing OpenGL hence the hunch for this fix)?

Adding

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

To application tag in the manifest would explicitly turn it off. And perhaps the issue will go away.

See this question with answers if you want to know: [if should use hardware acceleration or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432565/android-hardware-acceleration-to-use-or-not-to-use)

Comment: Maybe just putting in the certain `Activity` such as the AdActivity?