# Cardview is not working with layertype software

Tags: android, canvas, scrollview, cardview

I need to draw some path and show it below `Recyclerview`. So i have preferred following structure.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:padding="@dimen/d10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_menu"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/T_HEADER"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/d18sp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:alpha="0.6"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:padding="@dimen/d10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollGraph"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/d20dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutGraph"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewEvents"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textNoData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/TG_NO_DATA"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/d14sp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

I am able to draw my views and fill recyclerview. It seems okay.

Now my issue is that I am using `Cardview` to display items in `recyclerview`.

Following is the code of custom cell.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewGraph"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/d5dp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/d5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageTimeMap"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:layout_weight="1.8"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/bg_gray_placeholder"/>



            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:layout_weight="2.2"
                          android:orientation="vertical"
                          android:padding="@dimen/d3dp">

                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="center_vertical"
                              android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/textTimeMapType"
                              android:layout_width="0dp"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_weight="1"
                              android:drawablePadding="@dimen/d3dp"
                              android:gravity="center_vertical"
                              android:textSize="@dimen/d10sp"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageEditEvent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:padding="@dimen/d1dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ico_edit_gray"/>

                </LinearLayout>


                <TextView android:id="@+id/textTargetHead"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="0dp"
                          android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d3dp"
                          android:layout_weight="1"
                          android:alpha="0.8"
                          android:ellipsize="end"
                          android:gravity="center_vertical"
                          android:maxLines="2"
                          android:textColor="@color/colorActivityHeader"
                          android:textSize="@dimen/d11sp"/>



            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="@dimen/d11sp"/>
```

Now, As i need to draw long path in canvas, I have set `layertype=Software` in 'Srollview' so my view scrolls smoothly.

But when i use this property, `Cardview` does not set `corner-radius` or  `elevation`. If  remove this property from `Scrollview` then it works but my view laggs.

[image: Here is the screen shot of my graph]

Any one could help me with this issue?

Comment: show snippet of `canvas` drawing stuff. It may help

Comment: @Wizard  added screen shot

Comment: I guess, the view between two divider are `CardView`. correct?

Comment: Yes. It is showing flat. No elevation + no corner radius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got from [Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82329)

> Shadows are only supported with hardware rendering.

Apart from that,

I don't think enabling Hardware acceleration affect very much if your application uses only standard views.

[Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432565/android-hardware-acceleration-to-use-or-not-to-use) about when to use or not to use Hardware acceleration?
[Read more](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#determining) about how Hardware Acceleration works!

Comment: Cardview corner radius also not set. It also due to this layer type?

Comment: @Beena Yes, I can provide you reference link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599603/cardview-not-showing-shadow-in-android-l

Comment: @Beena But you can draw shadow manually though. on canvas I mean.