# HardwareAccelerated false removes elevation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-view, android-elevation

Setting hardware accelerated to false in my androidManifest removes elevation from my views..

When hardware accelerated is false, it removes elevation

When hardware accelerated is true, elevation is there but no smooth scrolling

Is there any way to solve this problem and i need both things in my app..

Answer (score 2):

You can't have elevation without hardware acceleration, so I suggest you set it true and find your problems, may be you draw something multiple time or ...

These links help you to solve your problem:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#tips
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16432999/1105277

If you really don't want to enable it, you can use these solutions:

- [Android View shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow)

Comment: I have scroll view also and My scrollview lags when i set hardware acceleration to truee....